# React table rows population issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate an html table based on a Rest web service call using React. Only table header was displayed. The table rows are blank. If I debug it, after line

```
tableModel.rows =  this.state.rows;
```

tableModel.rows was 'undefined'.

I counldn't figure out what's the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React Flux</title>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="color:red"></div>

        <script type="text/jsx">


            var tableModel = {
               cols: ["id", "name"],
               rows: [],
            }

            var Table = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function () {
                    return {text: ''};
                },
                componentDidMount: function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/user/findAll"
                    }).then(function(data) {
                        this.setState({            
                            rows: data});
                    }.bind(this))
                },
                render: function() {

                    tableModel.rows =  this.state.rows;

                    var _self = this;

                    var thead = React.DOM.thead({},
                       React.DOM.tr({},
                       this.props.cols.map(function (col) {
                       return React.DOM.th({}, col);
                    })));

                    var tbody = this.props.rows.map(function (row) {
                        return React.DOM.tr({},
                        _self.props.cols.map(function (col) {
                           return React.DOM.td({}, row[col] || "");
                        }));
                    });
                    return React.DOM.table({}, [thead, tbody]);
                }
            });

            React.render(<Table cols={tableModel.cols} rows={tableModel.rows} />, container);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `Table` `setState`, it's `render` function will be recall, but why do you think it's props would be repopulate? It stay the same, mean Table `this.props.rows === []`. You could fix it by put the `tableModel` into `Table state` and using `this.state` instead of `this.props`, or wrap another class to `Table` to manage data fetching and populate data to `Table` class.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yabah23s/2/ simple fiddle for you. Why don't you use JSX and React 0.14.x

Comment: I am not sure what can be written in JSX in this code. Can you clarify?